# Увеличение переменной до определённого момента, а после - снижение

Tags: java, формулы, логические-выражения

Есть слушатель кнопок, при нажатии на одну из кнопок значение переменной `x` должно увеличиваться до определённого значения (60), а после снижаться до 0. Вот как я попытался это сделать:

```
if(x >= 60){
    while(x >= 0){
        x -= y;
    }
}else{
    x += y;
}
```

Казалось бы всё нормально, но есть одна проблема. Переменная `x` используется в `actionPerformed` (реализация метода из класса `ActionListener`) методом `repaint()`.

Сама суть проблемы: при прибавлении картинка идёт плавно (постепенно прибавляя `y`, а не выдавая сразу конечный результат - 60), а когда понижается выходит лишь конечный результат (0), что не удивительно, ибо это цикл (в связи с тем, что он не обращает внимание на всё остальное, пока не закончит выполнение). Т.е. нужно как-то отслеживать изменение переменной в цикле или впихнуть туда действие (`repaint`)

Так вот вопрос, возможно ли как-то сделать "ссылку" на реализацию слушателя или `repaint()` (через объект уже пытался - бесполезно)? Либо нужна какая-то формула, по которой он сначала будет прибавлять до определённого момента, а после снижать (в идеале). Готов пробовать Ваши варианты, потому что сам я уже не знаю что делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если картинка увеличивается нормально, значит весь этот код так или иначе уже выполняется в цикле. И проблема как раз в том, что во время уменьшения не происходит прорисовка, в то время как при увеличении да. Вдаваться в подробности долго,просто надо отслеживать стадию другой переменной.

```
private boolean zoomIn = true; // поле для отслеживания состояния. 
// если true - то изображения в стадии увеличения
// false - уменьшения

... 
// в методе
if(zoomIn){
    if(x < 60){
        x+=y;
    }else{
        zoomIn = false;
    }
}else{
    if(x > 0){
        x-=y;
    }else{
        zoomIn = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 0;
int step = 1;
do {
    x += step;
    if (x == 60) {
        step *= -1;
    }
} (while x > 0);
```